# iPhone doesn't save password for Cisco IPsec VPN using racoon daemon

Tags: debian, ipsec, iphone, racoon

On my Debian server I had set up racoon daemon (1:0.8.0-14) for Cisco IPSec VPN using certificates for authentication. My racoon.conf is like following:

```
log info;
path certificate "/etc/racoon/certs";

listen {
    isakmp $SERVER_IP_HERE [500];
    isakmp_natt $SERVER_IP_HERE [4500];
}

timer {
    natt_keepalive 10 sec;
}

remote anonymous {
    lifetime time 24 hours;
    proposal_check obey;
    passive on;
    exchange_mode aggressive,main;
    my_identifier asn1dn;
    peers_identifier asn1dn;
    verify_identifier on;
    certificate_type x509 "cert_name.crt" "key_name.key";
    ca_type x509 "ca.crt";
    mode_cfg on;
    verify_cert on;
    ike_frag on;
    generate_policy on;
    nat_traversal on;
    dpd_delay 20;
    proposal {
        encryption_algorithm aes;
        hash_algorithm sha1;
        authentication_method xauth_rsa_server;
        dh_group modp1024;
    }
}

mode_cfg {
    conf_source local;

    auth_source system;
    auth_throttle 3;
    save_passwd on;

    dns4 8.8.8.8;
    network4 $SOME_LAN_SUBNET;
    netmask4 255.255.255.0;
    pool_size 128;
}

sainfo anonymous {
    pfs_group 2;
    lifetime time 24 hour;
    encryption_algorithm aes;
    authentication_algorithm hmac_sha1;
    compression_algorithm deflate;
}
```

I'm not using PSK authentication here. Using iPhone configuration utility I had uploaded all required certificates to iPhone and set up VPN on demand. Everything works just fine except for one thing: iPhone refuses to save VPN password regardless of `save_passwd on;` in racoon configuration file. As opposed to iPhone behaviour, Mac OS X 10.8.2 have no problems saving password. I had examined iPhone log file and found following:

```
racoon[151] <Notice>: >>>>> phase change status = phase 1 established
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration started.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: INTERNAL-IP4-ADDRESS = $SUBNET_IP_HERE.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: INTERNAL-IP4-MASK = 255.255.255.0.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: SAVE-PASSWORD = 0.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: INTERNAL-IP4-DNS = 8.8.8.8.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: BANNER = .
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: DEF-DOMAIN = .
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration: DEFAULT-ROUTE = local-address $SUBNET_IP_HERE/32.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Phase2 starting.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Network Configuration established.
configd[50] <Notice>: IPSec Phase1 established.
```

Please note IPSec Network Configuration message containing `SAVE-PASSWORD = 0.`. Is it a bug in racoon daemon on server, or iPhone (iOS version is 6.0.1 (10A523)) or it is me missing something? How to make iPhone remember IPSec VPN password?